# Ubuntu : unable to copy file to dir created under same credentials

Tags: permissions, files, sudo

I am Windows 7 remoting to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

I am new to Ubuntu ( and *nix in general ) and need to understand how permissions are assigned to newly created dirs.

Via Putty ssh session :

```
$bash
myaccount@mybox:/$ cd /etc/puppet
myaccount@mybox:/etc/puppet$ sudo mkdir device
myaccount@mybox:/etc/puppet/device$ 
myaccount@mybox:/etc/puppet/device$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 2 17:57
```

Then via WinSCP session ( SCP mode , also logged-in as myaccount@mybox ) I attempt to copy a file to /etc/puppet/device

However this operation fails with an error displayed in pop-up:

```
Error
Copying file 'myfile' failed.
scp: /etc/puppet/device/myfile: Permission denied
```

It seems logical to me that if my account is assigned sufficient rights to create a dir then it should also have rights to copy a file into that dir ?

Or do creating dirs and moving files fall under separate roles ?

NOTE: If you are going to down-tick my post, please explain why in a comment. Just anonymously down-ticking doesn't help me understand how these forums work. Seems like I'm playing by the rules, full details, following-up on comments, etc.

Comment: What are the rights on that folder? (Do a `ls /etc/puppet/device/`).

Comment: Can you please give the exact command line commands you have used? This will help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Please share exact and complete error message you get in WinSCP.

Comment: I have added info on exact commands , exact error messages , and permissions on the new dir.  Not sure why people are down-ticking my question ?  It seems like I've run into a barrier a lot of *nix newbies face.

Comment: Ok fair enough, but the About page says ServerFault is for professional systems administration questions - wouldn't that include Windows sysadmins learning *nix ? I am in a complex enterprise environment and it seems my question satisfies all the criteria spelled-out on the About page.

Comment: It's all about context.  This is kind of borderline, but... it's not so horrible.  However, I am going to migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In hope that I didn't overlook something:

- You used `sudo` to create a directory
- Your `ls` clearly states that the directory is owned by root
- When trying to copy files into that folder as user "myaccount" you are denied

This is normal behaviour. You have the following options:

- Grant write access to "others" (chmod o+w /etc/puppet/device => very bad idea)
- Create a group e.g. named "adm-puppet" and add all the users allowed to create files in that dir and the puppet user. Then change the group ownership to that group
- Add users allowed to write files in that directory to the exisisting puppet group
- Use extended [ACL](http://wiki.kaspersandberg.com/doku.php?id=howtos%3aacl)s

Comment: Thanks for the answer weeheavy , but here is what I find non-intuitive: I had to use `sudo mkdir` because myaccount doesn't have sufficient rights to execute file operations -- yet myaccount has the right to run sudo commands ! To my newbie eyes, this seems like a "loophole". In Windows, there is no sudo : a user that belongs to _local admins_ or _domain admins_ group inherits rights but still operates as that user.  Also, isn't there some way to run WinSCP as sudo ?

Comment: Isn't it a bit like UAC? Well I see your point, I don't like Ubuntu's global sudo, too. For specific tasks (restart daemon foo etc.) it's okay. Here's the explanation of Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

When you use sudo to create a file or a directory, you are running the command as root, so the file will of course be owned by root.

If you can't create the file/directory (minor hint: directories are just special files) as the normal user, root can "give" it to the normal user with `chown` (syntax `chown user:group file`).

If multiple users will need write access to the file, but not all, you will need to use a group; if you don't think a group is necessary you can use the group named after the user which usually exists (root and nobody are poor choices in such a situation, which is why users generally have individual groups also).

If you use a group with multiple users in it, you will also need to change the permissions to grant write access to the directory to the group.  Write access to a directory means the ability to create and remove files in it (execute is traverse, and read is list contents).  Do this with `chmod g+w dirname`.

Comment: Thanks for the resonse Falcon. When use say "the after the user which usually exists" and I understanding that the convention is for admins to create a parallel group for each user ?  I can see how this would be convenient for the purpose of assigning one user all the rights another user possesses. Is this the purpose ?